# Import project with different module name than directory to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to load a project called `flutterlocation` that I downloaded from github using git clone. The folder name is `flutterlocation/` but the module configuration file inside are called `location.iml` therefore when I open the project, Android Studio says that it cannot find `flutterlocation.iml` 
How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you're opening a project, Android Studio will checking if your current project has its `.iml` file. The `.iml` file is auto-generated by Android Studio and will use the same file name (minus .iml) with the project name.

In your case, you need to rename your `flutterlocation` project directory name to location to match the previous `.iml` file. Then, you can refactor the project to use the correct one.

Another solution is by closing the project then removing the `.iml` file. Then import the project to tell the Android Studio to auto-generated the `.iml` file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close your Android Studio.
2. Go to the project root directory and **delete the `location.iml`** file.
3. **Open** the project using Android Studio (**NOT** **import** project). Android Studio now will automatically generate the correct `flutterlocation.iml` file for you.